# How to get width of a table header cell in JavaScript via DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the access to this DOM node in `temp1.$el`.

And here is the content which the above variable has:

```
<table id="__BVID__730" aria-busy="false" aria-colcount="10" aria-rowcount="14" class="table b-table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-class-hidden">
        <tr>
            <th aria-colindex="1" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Header1 Name
                </div>
            </th>
            <th aria-colindex="2" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Header2 Name
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        <tr class="">
            <td aria-colindex="1" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Row1 Column1 Value
                </div>
            </td>
            <td aria-colindex="2" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Row1 Column2 Value
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm working in plain JavaScript and what I need to get is the width of the element under:

```
 table thead tr th (child-1)
 table thead tr th (child-2)
```

I tried many things like:

```
temp1.$el.tHead.firstElementChild.children[0].offsetWidth
temp1.$el.tHead.firstElementChild.children[0].clientWidth    
temp1.$el.tHead.firstElementChild.children[0].firstElementChild.offsetWidth
temp1.$el.tHead.firstElementChild.children[0].firstElementChild.clientWidth
```

But all of them are not working. The `table thead tr th` widths depends of the actual content inside of them, and I need to take the widths and later to apply them on a different table.

I managed to get them to the variable `temp1.$el` but from here, I'm not able to success to get the widths that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could get this done using the ParentNode property [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).

> The [ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) property **children** is a read-only property that returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which contains all of the child [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) of the node upon which it was called.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('__BVID__730');
console.log(element.tHead.children[0].children[0].offsetWidth)
```

```html
<table id="__BVID__730" aria-busy="false" aria-colcount="10" aria-rowcount="14" class="table b-table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-class-hidden">
        <tr>
            <th aria-colindex="1" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Header1 Name
                </div>
            </th>
            <th aria-colindex="2" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Header2 Name
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="">
        <tr class="">
            <td aria-colindex="1" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Row1 Column1 Value
                </div>
            </td>
            <td aria-colindex="2" class="">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    Row1 Column2 Value
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the $el? This looks like **jQuery**, and not vanilla js.

Based on your code.

```
// Table
// Or querySelector('table') if you have only one
const table = document.getElementById("__BVID__730"); 
console.log(table.clientWidth);

// Thead & Tbody
const thead = table.querySelector("thead");
const tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
console.log(thead.clientWidth);
console.log(tbody.clientWidth);

// Tr th
const theadColumns = thead.querySelectorAll("tr th");
if (theadColumns) {
  console.log(theadColumns[0]);
  console.log(theadColumns[1]);

  // OR
  theadColumns.forEach(column => console.log(column.clientWidth));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo to get width of first th (Used jQuery 1.8.3):

http://jsfiddle.net/7dg5bvou/

Also this might help you solve your problem:
first include jQuery library in head section of your HTML.

```
temp1.$el.find("table[id='__BVID__730']").find(".thead-class-hidden").children("tr:first-child").children("th:first-child").width();
```

Also you can use `"eq"` to find respective element like: `td:eq(1)`